# Google Adwords API Report Utilities - selector expected

Tags: .net, google-ads-api

I'm testing report usage with a Google Adwords API test account. I have the following code to download an [Adgroup Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#ad-group):

```
    ReportDefinition definition = new ReportDefinition()
    {
        reportName = "Adgroup Report",
        reportType = ReportDefinitionReportType.ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT,
        downloadFormat = DownloadFormat.CSVFOREXCEL,
        dateRangeType = ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.YESTERDAY,
        selector = new Selector
        {
            fields = new string[] { "Clicks" }
        }
    };

    ReportUtilities utilities = new ReportUtilities(user) { ReportVersion = "v201206" };
    ClientReport report = utilities.DownloadClientReport(definition, reportPath);
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> Invalid ReportDefinition Xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'selector'. One of '{"https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201206":id, "https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201206":selector}' is expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a quick glance, your report definition looks correct to me. However, Adwords API version `v201206` is sunset. Try using `v201306` and see whether this makes the error go away. If not, have a look at the actual XML that is created and sent.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed this - I didn't realize I had written 2012. I tried the v201206 but got the same error. Then I tried v201302 - which I believe is the version the .NET library I downloaded is using (which I was able to tell looking at the generated XML), and it worked!